# How can retrieve the linked in profile information using Java programming language?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, profile

I want to get the public profile information of a person using public linkedin url to my local database whenever the person changes the profile information on linkedin using programmatically. Is there any suggestion for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the plain java file to login to linked in and then you can fetch the .html file from linked in. The .html page contains the person contact information. To parse the content from html file, there are html file related libraries. you can use them.